# Where is the cfnbootstrap folder?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm curious about some AWS internals - I don't have an actual issue, I just want to learn more about this.

I'm running Beanstalk with Windows instances.

I was poking around some logs in c:\cfn and in "C:\cfn\log\cfn-init.log" and I found some lines like this:

```
  File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 159, in _retry
  File "cfnbootstrap\msi_tool.pyc", line 100, in _msi_from_url
  File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 79, in __init__
  File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 573, in check_status
  File "cfnbootstrap\packages\requests\models.pyc", line 834, in raise_for_status
```

So I searched the server's HDD and found no cfnbootstrap folder or any *.pyc files.

Where is this folder and these Python scripts located? I'd like to have a look at these scripts (maybe even try to decompile the pyc files) and see what it's actually doing.

### Edit

So it's a Python module, but it seems Python isn't installed on my Beanstalk Windows instance (or at least I can't find it anywhere). Does Beanstalk not even use this for Windows?

Comment: added info to my answer on how the Python scripts are packaged using [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ) for the Windows installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cfnbootstrap`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html) is a Python package containing various CloudFormation helper scripts.

The latest version of the Amazon Linux AMI has the AWS CloudFormation helper scripts installed by default in `/opt/aws/bin`, and the underlying `cfnbootstrap` Python package can be found in the OS Python shared packages directory at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/`.

On Windows-based Elastic Beanstalk instances, the [`cfn-bootstrap` MSI package](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-win64-latest.msi) gets installed to to `C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap`. For the MSI package the Python files are compiled into self-contained `.exe` files using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ), so a global Python installation is not required on the instance, and all of the Python source files are contained in `library.zip` in the package directory.

See the [CloudFormation Helper Scripts Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html) documentation for more information on this package.