# Create systemd service in AWS Elastic Beanstalk on new Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, systemd

I'm currently trying to create a worker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk which is pulling messages from a specific SQS queue (with the help of the Symfony messenger). I don't want to use dedicated worker instances for this task. After some research, I found out that systemd can help here which is enabled by default on the new Amazon Linux 2 instances.

However, I'm not able to create a running systemd service. Here is my .ebextensions/03_workers.config file:

```html
files:
    /etc/systemd/system/my_worker.service:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            [Unit]
            Description=My worker

            [Service]
            User=nginx
            Group=nginx
            Restart=always
            ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php /var/app/current/bin/console messenger:consume integration_incoming --time-limit=60

            [Install]
            WantedBy=multi-user.target

services:
    systemd:
        my_worker:
            enabled: "true"
            ensureRunning: "true"
```

I can't see my service running if I'm running this command:

```html
systemctl | grep my_worker
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`systemd` is not supported in [Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-services). The only correct is `sysvinit`:

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    my_worker:
      enabled: "true"
      ensureRunning: "true"
```

But I don't think it will even work, as this is for Amazon Linux 1, not for Amazon Linux 2.

In Amazon Linux 2 you shouldn't be even using much of  `.ebextensions`. AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) specifically write:

> On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, instead of providing files and commands in .ebextensions configuration files, we **highly recommend that you use Buildfile. Procfile, and platform hooks** whenever possible to configure and run custom code on your environment instances during instance provisioning.

Thus, you should consider using [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) which does basically what you want to achieve:

> Use a Procfile for **long-running application processes that shouldn't exit**. Elastic Beanstalk expects processes run from the Procfile to **run continuously**. Elastic Beanstalk monitors these processes and **restarts any process that terminates**. For short-running processes, use a Buildfile.

**Alternative**

Since you already have created a unit file `/etc/systemd/system/my_worker.service` for `systemd`, you can `enable` and `start` it yourself.

For this [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) in `.ebextensions` can be used. For example:

```
container_commands:
   10_enable_worker:
     command: systemctl enable worker.service
   20_start_worker:
     command: systemctl start worker.service
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments & thoughts. I seems like Procfiles are not supported for the PHP platform. So if I want to use my worker queues, I seems like I have to downgrade to Amazon Linux 1 to use "sysvinit".

Comment: @AlexanderBarton No problem. You don't have to downgrade at all. Instead of using `services` section in `.ebexternsions`, you use `container_commands`. I will extend the answer with example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your alternative solution is working perfectly and of course make sense ;) You really have saved my day!

Comment: I have done it! It's my first question and I had to search for the acceptance button in the UI ^^

Comment: @AlexanderBarton Thank you. It can be hard to find in the beginning. :-)

Comment: For PHP/Laravel applications, I've found that platform hooks works pretty well. Just add a systemd service and you'd be fine. 
But using container commands to control (start) an unregistered service causes deployment to fail - when EB is sprouting an extra instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not [officially documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-services), but you *can* use a systemd service in Amazon Linux 2.

A block like the following should work:

```
services: 
    systemd:
        __SERVICE_NAME__:
            enabled: true
            ensureRunning: true
```

Support for a "systemd" service is provided by internal package /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/[cfnbootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625373/where-is-the-cfnbootstrap-folder)/construction.py which lists recognized service types: `sysvinit`, `windows`, and `systemd`

```
class CloudFormationCarpenter(object):
    _serviceTools = {"sysvinit": SysVInitTool, "windows": WindowsServiceTool, "systemd": SystemDTool}
```

Note that a systemd service must support [chkconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133552/service-doesnt-support-chkconfig) and in particular your launch script at `/etc/init.d/__SERVICE_NAME__` must include a "chkconfig" and "description" line similar to:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 70 60
# description: Continuously logs Nginx status.
```

If you don't support chkconfig correctly then `chkconfig --list __SERVICE_NAME__` will print an error, and attempting to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk will log a more detailed error in `/var/log/cfn-init.log` when it tries to start the service.